# Undefined control sequence \accentset when using todonotes package

Tags: accents, todonotes

I'm trying to use `todonotes` together with the `accent` package, but the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\todo{$\accentset{\circ}{x}$}
\end{document}
```

gives the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
    \accentset #1#2->\begingroup \def \cc@a 
                                                {#1}\let \math@bgroup \@empty \def \...
        l.7 \todo{$\accentset{\circ}{x}$}
```

There seems to be a problem with using `\accentset` inside `\todo`, but I really don't know what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to protect `\accentset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\todo{$\protect\accentset{\circ}{x}$}{$y$}
\end{document}
```

However, this is not specific to `\todo`, e.g. `\section` and the like have the same issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
%\section{$\accentset{\circ}{x}$} % throws an error
\section{$\protect\accentset{\circ}{x}$}  % fine
%\todo{$\accentset{\circ}{x}$}{$y$} % throws an error
\todo{$\protect\accentset{\circ}{x}$}{$y$} % fine
\end{document}
```

[image]